# How could I add a responsive design to this flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm having trouble getting this guitar I have built with CSS to be responsive. I would like the body of the guitar and the neck to remain static and just get cut off as the screen resizes. However I am unsure how to do this as I am using flexbox to lay it out. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.
[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/JustinThyme/pen/xzBEwj)

```
/*I was required to post this code please see the link above*/
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.guitar {
  margin-top: 1px;
  border: 2px solid #3A434A;
  background-color: #EDEDEE;
  height: 300px;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no huge differences about using flexbox or not to create responsive things. So you just need to write appropriate rules for mobile view. It's possible to do with @media

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { /* your code for mobile here */ }
```

It's not clear to me about what actually you trying to achieve for mobile view. It would be nice if you could provide a screenshot or so that will represent what's on your mind ;)